# Is there a way to run only failed test cases in azure devpos?

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I Have category with some of test cases for ex(2 test cases, 1 test case passed & the second one failed)
I need to run only the failed test case when run this release for the second time

when I enabled "re-run" opting in test assemblies, both test cases run but I need to rnu only failed test case

I there a way in Azure devops allows me to run only failed test cases?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no such way present. Every run of the build pipeline the unit test gate will run compltely

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way in Azure devops allows me to run only failed test cases?

Yes. I suggest that you can use the `rerunFailedTests` feature in Visual Studio Test task. Then it will re-run failed tests.

Here is an example:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testPlan'
  inputs:
    testSelector: testPlan
    testPlan: xx
    testSuite: xx
    testConfiguration: 1
    rerunFailedTests: true
    rerunMaxAttempts: 2
```

Refer to this doc about [Visual Studio Test Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops).

> rerunFailedTests

> Rerun failed tests:  Selecting this option will rerun any failed tests until they pass or the maximum # of attempts is reached.

Comment: This option will re-run the failed test cases within the same release, but I need when run next release only selected failed test cases from previous release

Comment: In this case, i am afraid that there is no such method can achieve it. Next Release will start new test execution

Comment: I was thinking about workaround to solve this issue, if there is a middleware in azure makes me update the database with the test results of pipeline. and then take these failed cases & re-run it for next release . I don't know if it possible or not?